# TestCafe RequestLogger - How to implement for every request in the test framework

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

We are trying to track down a network issue in our company which causes a Browser Disconnect General Error. I want to use `RequestLogger` timestamp to help us highlight when this intermittent issue occurs and also any additional request/response information at that time.

In the Request Logger documentation the `.requestHooks(logger)` is initiated at every test case level. And then `console.log(logRecord.X.X)` is used to log the record at that specific time.

But how can I have a continuous logging throughout my whole test framework without using `console.log(logRecord.X.X)` on every line?

Is it somehow possible to have the `RequestLogger` continuously running via my test-runner function?

```
if(nodeConfig.util.getEnv('NODE_ENV') == "jenkins-ci")
        {
            // @ts-ignore
            // createTestCafe("localhost", port1, port2).then(tc => {
            createTestCafe().then(tc => {
                this.testcafe = tc;
                this.runner = this.testcafe.createRunner();

                return this.runner
                    .src(testPath)
                    .filter(filterSettings)
                    .browsers(environment.browserToLaunch)
                    .concurrency(environment.concurrencyAmount)
                    .reporter(reporterSettings)
                    .run(runSettingsCi);
            })
            .then(failedCount => {
                console.log('Location ' + testPath + ' tests failed: ' + failedCount);
                this.testcafe.close();
                process.exit(0);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Location ' + testPath + ' General Error');
                console.log(err);
                this.testcafe.close();
                process.exit(1);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TestCafe doesn't allow attaching request hooks with the test runner class. At the same time, you can attach it to each fixture. [RequestLogger](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requestlogger/) will collect information about all requests.

For example:

```
import { Selector, RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

const logger = RequestLogger();

fixture `Log all requests`
    .page`devexpress.github.io/testcafe`
    .requestHooks(logger)
    .afterEach(() => console.log(logger.requests));

test('Test 1', async t => {
    await t
        .click(Selector('span').withText('Docs'))
        .click(Selector('a').withText('Using TestCafe'))
        .click(Selector('a').withText('Test API'));
});

test('Test 2', async t => {
    await t
        .click(Selector('span').withText('Docs'))
        .click(Selector('a').withText('Continuous Integration'))
        .click(Selector('a').withText('How It Works'));
});
```

Comment: Super. Thank you @Dmitry

Comment: Hi @Vladimir A. do you know how we can comprehend this solution in gherkin-testcafe environment as that BDD style framework doesn't allow requestHooks at feature level. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Previously, TestCafe allowed you to attach request hooks to one test or fixture at a time. In the new TestCafe v1.19.0, you can also define **global request hook**s in a JavaScript configuration file `.testcaferc.js` to attach them to all fixtures and tests within a test run. You can learn more here: [Global Request Hoo](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#request-hooks)[ks](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#request-hooks).

Please note that you can use the `configFile` option in [CLI](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--config-file-path) and [program API](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402662/reference/testcafe-api/global/createtestcafe#options) to specify the path to a config file.

For the initial usage scenario, you can use the following example:

```js
const { RequestLogger } = require('testcafe');
 
const logger = RequestLogger();
 
module.exports = {
   hooks: {
       request: logger,
   },
};
```